# Cannot get launchctl to run python script

Tags: launchd, python, plist

I wrote a basic python web scraping program and am trying to get it to run automatically at 4 am every day but am having no luck. The .plist file and python code are as follows:

.plist:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8”?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC “-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN” “http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd”>
<plist version=“1.0”>
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.nba.game.log.scraper</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/user/Code/Scripts/Web\ Scraping/Sports/Basketball/NBA/nba_game_log_scraper.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>4</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import time

teams = {'ATL': 'Atlanta Hawks', 'BOS': 'Boston Celtics', 'BRK': 'Brooklyn Nets',
        'CHO': 'Charlotte Hornets', 'CHI': 'Chicago Bulls', 'CLE': 'Cleveland Cavaliers',
        'DAL': 'Dallas Mavericks', 'DEN': 'Denver Nuggets', 'DET': 'Detroit Pistons',
        'GSW': 'Golden State Warriors', 'HOU': 'Houston Rockets', 'IND': 'Indiana Pacers',
        'LAC': 'Los Angeles Clippers', 'LAL': 'Los Angeles Lakers', 'MEM': 'Memphis Grizzlies',
        'MIA': 'Miami Heat', 'MIL': 'Milwaukee Bucks', 'MIN': 'Minnesota Timberwolves',
        'NOP': 'New Orleans Pelicans', 'NYK': 'New York Knicks', 'OKC': 'Oklahoma City Thunder',
        'ORL': 'Orlando Magic', 'PHI': 'Philadelphia 76ers', 'PHO': 'Phoenix Suns',
        'POR': 'Portland Trail Blazers', 'SAC': 'Sacramento Kings', 'SAS': 'San Antonio Spurs',
        'TOR': 'Toronto Raptors', 'UTA': 'Utah Jazz', 'WAS': 'Washington Wizards'}
years = 2023

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

for team in teams.keys():
    # build the soup
    url = f'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{team}/{years}/gamelog/'
    source = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')
    
    # get the headers
    header = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]
    header = header[1:]

    # get the rows
    rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
    log = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range(len(rows))]
    log = log[1:]

    # split into two dataframes, one for the team and one for opponents
    game_log = pd.DataFrame(log, columns=header)
    r_headers = game_log.iloc[:, 0:7]
    team_log_temp = game_log.iloc[:, 7:23]
    opp_log_temp = game_log.iloc[:, 24:40]
    opp_log = pd.merge(r_headers, opp_log_temp, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    team_log = pd.merge(r_headers, team_log_temp, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    opp_log = opp_log.rename(columns={'\xa0':'H/A'})
    team_log = team_log.rename(columns={'\xa0':'H/A'})

    # export to a csv file
    team_output_file = f'{team}_{years}_team_game_log.csv'
    opp_output_file = f'{team}_{years}_opp_game_log.csv'
    output_dir = Path(f'/Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Archive/Data/Sports/Basketball/NBA/{teams[team]}')
    output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    team_log.to_csv(output_dir / team_output_file)
    opp_log.to_csv(output_dir / opp_output_file)

    # wait a few seconds to not get blocked
    time.sleep(3)
```

The python file works fine when run from terminal and has permissions `-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  staff  2606 Nov 13 12:31 nba_game_log_scraper.py` when running `ls -l`. launchctl attempt to run the script at the right time but it exits with error code `78` and /var/log/system.log gives the error

```
Nov 19 12:58:34 user-MacBook-Air-95 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (local.nba.game.log.scraper[9018]): Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
Nov 19 12:58:34 user-MacBook-Air-95 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (local.nba.game.log.scraper[9018]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
```

after running `launchctl start local.nba.game.log.scraper` from terminal. The .plist file permissions are also `-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  567 Nov 19 12:30 local.nba.game.log.scraper.plist`.

Full path of .plist file is `/Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/local.nba.game.log.scraper.plist` and the path of the python file is `/Users/user/Code/Scripts/Web Scraping/Sports/Basketball/NBA/nba_game_log_scraper.py`.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but it might be that you're trying to import modules that aren't in the standard search path. launchd jobs do not have your normal shell environment, so it won't have anything like `PYTHONPATH` defined. You can add it with an `EnvironmentVariables` array in the .plist. Also, for debugging, you can add `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys to your .plist to record any informative error messages it prints as it tries to run.